# Populating PostgreSQL DB using bitcoind RPCs and API

Tags: postgresql, api, rpc, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm attempting to create a PostgreSQL database with block data on:

Hash, total transactions, height, time, merkle root, confirmations, difficulty, bits, size (bytes), version, nonce

And transaction data on:

Hash, Txid, Size (bytes), confirmations, fee, time, amount, addresses

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to use the bitcoin daemon RPCs/API to get the data, so that I can put it into the database.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to have acces to the information of blocks and transactions. Choose one of these

- Install Bitcoin full node on linux/windows/mac
- Run a Docker container with a Bitcoin full node. There are many (I created this for myself https://github.com/jmaister/bitcoin-docker)
- Query API to http://blockchain.info

Then, query every block and its transactions, from block 0 to current one (496764 as of now) and store this information through SQL to your PostgreSQL database.

To query blocks and transactions from a Bitcoin node, use the JSON/RPC API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!